# How this C code working. I'm getting 56 as output for '\08'

Tags: c

*Output of this code is 56.*

**// Output : 56**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c = '\08';
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your constant consists of 2 bytes '\0' and '8'. These are truncated to '8' when stored in c.

Comment: The important part might be *why* this is 2 bytes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @stark commented, Your constant consists of 2 bytes '\0' and '8'. These are truncated to '8' when stored in the variable `c`.

In [ASCII Character Chart](https://www.eso.org/~ndelmott/ascii.html) you can see that 8 is 56 in ASCII, and you get that because you use the `%d` format specifier to print:

[image]

You could have seen that yourself, if you paid attention to your warnings:

```
main.c:4:14: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    4 |     char c = '\08';
      |
```

Moreover, I suggest you try printing like this:

```
printf("%c", c);
```

and then the output would be:

> 8

which shows you what was really stored in the variable `c`.

---

Tip: If you use `char c = '\01';` or `char c = '\07';` and anything in between, you will see *no warning* and the corresponding number being printed, because these are valid octal digits, as @Gerhardh's answer mentions.

Comment: But when i change 8 with other no less than eight it simply print the same no. not its ASCII  value 
for example : c = '\01' prints 1 instead of 49

Comment: @ShivamTyagi please see my anser. Digits below 8 are valid octal digits and extend the escaped value. The first character that is no valid octal digit is treated as the next separate character.

Comment: @ShivamTyagi if you use anything in between `\01` and `\07`, you will see *no warning*, because there are **valid octal digits**. See my updater answer for more, or simply check Gerhardh's. :)

Comment: thanks 
now i understand how this works :)

Answer (score 4):

In C strings or character literals, it is possible to escape hexadecimal or octal values.

the prefix `'\0'` is used for octal values, while `'\x'` is used for hex values.
This means `'\0'` is equal to value 0, `'\011'` is equal to 9 etc.

In your case a `'8'` follows which is no valid octal digit. Therefore the escape sequence stops there and your literal is same as value 0 followed by character `'8'`.

Now you have a character literal with more than 1 character. This is a multibyte character literal and the value of this literal is implementation dependend.
In your case the final value of the character is the value of the last character, e.g. `'8'` which has ascii value `0x38` or `56`.

As you print this as a decimal number, you get `56`.

Answer (score 0):

Its taking value of '8' as char. In ASCII its 56. Basicly char holds only 1 character